# Laravel localization with Voyager admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, voyager

I'm making a Laravel website with Voyager admin and now I need to add localization to that website. Voyager includes its own translations table and I'm using it for creating content in multiple languages from backend. But in the frontend routing is not working, I'm getting `NotFoundHttpException` error. My routes are as following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'fr'], function()
{
    App::setLocale('fr');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'PageController@show');
    Route::get('posts/{slug}', 'PostsController@show');
    //and so on
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what URL is not working?

Comment: what version of laravel?

Comment: Version is 5.5 . Any url that is working without language prefix isn't working with it, for example, `/posts/hello` is working, but `fr/posts/hello` is showing `NotFoundHttpException `

Comment: Can you post the rest of your routes file?

Comment: are you declaring the route for `posts/hello` earlier in the file?

Comment: [Routes file](https://pastebin.com/BU9H0wNW)

Comment: try moving it to the top

Comment: before Route::resource('/news', 'NewsController');

Comment: That way it works, but still shows the english version of the post. I guess `setLocale` is not working for some reason.

Comment: Seems like a Voyager issue, it's multilanguage support is verys strange. I'll try to change my controllers. Thank you vey much for your help :)

Comment: do you have your translations properly set up? I guess you can check whether the locale is right by dying in the controller die(App::getLocale())

Comment: `App::getLocale()` is returning correct value, but content is not being retrieved correctly. I think it needs to be improved, because Voyager is saving translated content in a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups) you can go

`Route::prefix('admin')->group` so

```
Route::prefix('fr')->group(function()
{
    App::setLocale('fr');
    Route::get('{slug}', 'PageController@show');
    Route::get('posts/{slug}', 'PostsController@show');
    //and so on
});
```

AND also the order is important.

Comment: can you give me more info? What url are you trying? What error? what version of laravel?

Comment: I answered in the comments of original post.